# Getting following exception when calling the service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web, asp.net-web-api

I am getting following exception when Calling the demandware OCAPI services from the web api.This comes when calling logout and Basket API.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<html>
     <head>     
        <title>Transmission problem</title>     
        <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="/waroot/style.css"> 
    </head> 

    <body>
        <h1>Transmission Problems</h1>  
        <img src="/waroot/system_arrow.gif" width="21" height="21" alt="" border="0">   
        <p class="system_info">
            The request couldn't be processed correctly. Please try again soon.
        </p>    
        <hr> 
     </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: I would suggest that you study the documentation of the API you are using in program

Answer (score 0):

Check the **error*** and **customerror*** blade log files on the Demandware instance you are accessing through OCAPI. You could access them from **Business Manager > Administration > 
Site Development > Development Setup > WebDav Access (Log files)**
If there is no evidence of what could be the problem in these log files, raise a ticket with the Demandware Support to check the OCAPI setup on your Demandware instance.